# Rearrangement of letters in a word

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I have the following exercise, how many ways are there two rearrange the letters in the word “apple”. I know that the answer will be $5!/2$, as we have $5!$ permutations, but as we have $2$ "p"s we counted twice every different permutation.

I would like to get the same result using a more formal argument. We had in the lecture the following argument (which is I think used implicitly in my argumentation):

Let $Y,X$ be sets. Suppose we have a disjoint partition  $ Y = \dot\bigcup_{x\in X} Y_x$ with $\#Y_x =m$. Then $\#X = \frac{\#Y}{m}$.
Am I right that this is used implicitly and what are my $Y_x$ precisely.

Comment: No.  It is better to think of this as $\dfrac{5!}{2!1!1!1!}$.  Since you appear to be in a combinatorics course, you should have heard of binomial coefficients.  Well, for this you should read about [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: I know what the multinomial coefficent is, but in this course of combinatoric we havn't discussed it yet, so I think it should be possible do it without it. We had the most of combinatorical principals (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles) in particular the rule of sum, division,m product, double counting, bijective proof and pigenhole principle. Is it possible to somehow use this to solve that i.e write down the set I want to count and use some of this rules to count it?

Comment: The multinomial coefficient can be described as a product of binomial coefficients.  (*Choose where the a goes, then choose where the p's go, then choose where the l goes, etc...*).  It could also be described by way of "division by symmetry" as you seem to have started, however the amount of symmetry here at play is $m!$, not just $m$.  Both approaches should be accessible at an early level of studying combinatorics even if it has not yet been formally introduced.

Comment: Let consider set $Y$ as set of permutations of a,p,**p**,l,e. Then $\#Y=5!$ Let consider disjoint partition of $Y$ into subsets $Y_x$ each of those is the same sequence of letters. Then $\#Y_x=2$ and $\#X=\frac{5!}{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Is "no" really the best answer to this question? The lemma OP posted at the end of their answer is the theoretical underpinning of the multinomial formula anyway. When you bluntly say no, you make it seem like the $Y/X/Y_x$ theorem is not useful, when in fact it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the theorem you mentioned is being used implicitly. Here are the details of how that theorem is applied to "APPLE" permutation problem.

$Y$ is the set of permutations of the word $AP_1P_2LE$. All letters are distinct, since $P_1$ and $P_2$ have been given labels that distinguish them. Therefore, $\#Y=5!$.

$X$ is the set of permutations of the word $APPLE$, where the two copies of $P$ are identical.

For each $x\in X$, we let $Y_x$ be the two resulting words that result from labeling the $P$'s in $x$ in two different ways. For example, if $x=PAPEL$, then $Y_x=\{P_1AP_2EL,\;P_2AP_1EL\}$. Note that each $\#Y_x=2!$, because there are $2$ copies of the letter $P$ in each rearrangement, which can be labeled with $1$ and $2$ in $2!$ ways.

Since $Y$ is the disjoint union of $Y_x$ over all possible $x\in X$, we conclude that
$\#X=\#Y/\#Y_x=5!/2!$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was searching for!